# How can I close a stream without knowing its name?

Tags: streams

If I initialise a stream as follows

```
OpenWrite["~/example"]
```

How do I close this stream?  `Close` seems to expect a name, but I do not know the name of the stream in this format.

[edit] - Thanks for all the responses.  It seems the simplest solution was

```
Close[<full path name to file>]
```

I had previously tried Close["~/example"] but to no avail.

Comment: Check `Streams[]` for it.  When you use `OpenWrite`, you'd normally save the return value (the stream object), otherwise you can't use the stream at all.  So under normal usage, this would not be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`OpenWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenWrite.html) returns the stream it opens, so do this

```
str = OpenWrite["~/example"]
```

> ```
> OutputStream["/Users/oldmg/example", 83]
> ```

```
Close[str]
```

Also, all streams have a name. In this case it is "/Users/oldmg/example".

Answer (score 3):

In the event you did not save the stream object for some reason,
You should be able to close by the file name, ie. simply

```
 Close["~/example"]
```

Comment: Won't work. The stream name has "~" expanded to the full path.

Comment: Use `Close[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "example"}]]` instead.

Comment: You can also use `Close[ExpandFileName["~/example"]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Typical usage:

```
(Write[#, "file contents"]; Close[#]) &@OpenWrite["test"];
(Print@Read[#]; Close[#]) &@OpenRead["test"];
(*
file contents
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, most general way to do this is probably via Streams[].

Set up some data ...

```
test = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}], 
   50] (* sample data ... *); 
str = StringToStream[#] & /@ 
  StringSplit[test]; (* converted to streams *)
```

Now the example ...

```
Streams[] (* all streams *)
ostr = Select[Streams[], SameQ[Head[#], InputStream] &] (* select inputStreamsonly *);
Close[#] & /@ ostr (* now close all the input streams ... *);
Streams[] (* only output streams remain*)
```

Comment: `WithCleanup` is a good tool for close the stream